# Isomorphism of finite generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

$A$, $B$, $C$ are finite generated modules over $F$, where $F$ is PID.
$A \oplus B  \cong A \oplus C$
Is $B \cong C$?
Please give me some direction, i don`t have any specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID. Each
has the form
$$M\cong F^n\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^n F/(p_i^{n_i}F)$$
where the $p_i$ are irreducibles. Uniqueness holds: $M$ determines
$n$ and the $p_i$ and $n_i$ up to trivialities such as order and
replacing an irreducible by an associate.